# How get the columnames from select query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Is it possible to get the column names using a query in MySQL? For example, I have a SELECT query:

```
SELECT name AS 'name', surname AS 'col1', last_name AS 'col2' FROM tb_people;
```

So, I want to get "Only with one SQL query" like:

```
    Columns or alias of my query
    --------
    name
    col1
    col2
```

I try something similar to:

```
SHOW COLUMNS (SELECT name AS 'name', surname AS 'col1', last_name AS 'col2' FROM tb_people)
```

And with

```
DESCRIBE (SELECT name AS 'name', surname AS 'col1', last_name AS 'col2' FROM tb_people)
```

But these return SQL errors.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this in your application? MySql API in most languages provide functions to fetch all sorts of field information including name from the results returned by MySql. For example in PHP you can use `mysql_fetch_field()` on the results returned by `mysql_query()` to fetch field information.

This is how it is done in PHP, there must be equivalent functions in the language you are using:

```
$res = mysql_query( "SELECT name AS 'name', surname AS 'col1', last_name AS 'col2' FROM tb_people" );
for( $i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields( $res ); ++$i ) {
     $fieldInfo = mysql_fetch_field( $res, $i );
     echo $fieldInfo[ 'name' ].'<br />';
}
```

results:

```
name
col1
col2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my question i try to say without any server language. So, it's a valid answer to PHP developers.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have used this successfully in the past, but I don't know if it compatible with all versions:

```
SELECT name FROM syscolumns 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects 
WHERE name= 'MyTableName') 
ORDER by colorder
```

If you installed MySQL server 5, you may get around this problem easily:

```
use information_schema

SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C limit 5 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Cheers!

Comment: Your answer is about real table column names, but he wants to get column names or aliases which are generated by a particular query.

Comment: The first query, with syscolumns and sysobjects, is something that MSSQL has, not MySQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in efect, i'm refering to alias names not phisycal columns.

Comment: @theabibo: Are you executing this query from the database itself or from a WebApp? If you are calling this from your application you can use regex along with the standard string builder concept for Data Access with mySQL.